# How come file is not excluded with gsutil rsync -x by the Google Cloud Builder?

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform, rsync, google-cloud-build

I am currently running the gsutil rsync cloud build command:

```
gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
-m rsync -r -c -d -x "\.gitignore" . gs://mybucket/
```

I am using the `-x "\.gitignore"` argument here to try and not copy over the `.gitignore` file, as mentioned here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync

However, when looking in the bucket and the logs, it still says:

`2021-04-23T13:29:37.870382893Z Step #1: Copying file://./.gitignore [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...`

So `rsync` is still copying over the file despite the `-x "\.gitignore"` argument.

According to the docs `-x` is a Python regexp, so `//./.gitignore` should be captured by `\.gitignore`

[image]

Does anyone know why this isn't working and why the file is still being copied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [`rsync.py`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/master/gslib/commands/rsync.py#L755) source code:

> `if cls.exclude_pattern.match(str_to_check):`

In Python, `re.match` only returns a match if it occurs at the start of string.

So, in order to find a match anywhere using the `-x` parameter, you need to prepend the pattern you need to find with `.*` or with `(?s).*`:

```py
gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
-m rsync -r -c -d -x ".*\.gitignore" . gs://mybucket/
```

Note that to make sure `.gitignore` appears at the end of string, you need to append `$`, `-x ".*\.gitignore$"`.